# Can't Copy/Paste to VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

Today, I just setup a new VM, from here.

https://www.vmware.com/go/downloadplayer

So, I set it up and everything seems to be working fine.  I can definitely login with my password, but I can't copy/paste anything from my laptop to the new VM.  I tried to run this code: 'sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools'.  That, supposedly will allow me to copy/paste.  However, when I enter that, I'm prompted for my password on the VM.  I enter it, and get a message that it's not correct.  I've done this 3x; the password is definitely correct, or I couldn't even login to the VM.  Can someone tell me what's going on?  All I want to do is copy/paste.  That's it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Copy and Paste in VMWare settings, e.g. like [that](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.server_configclassic.doc_41/esx_server_config/security_deployments_and_recommendations/t_enable_copy_and_paste_operations_between_the_guest_operating_system_and_remote_console.html).

Comment: I saw this link yesterday.  In my setup (VMware Workstation 14 Player), there is no Summary 'Tab' and no 'Edit Settings'.  All I have is 'Applications', 'Places', and 'System'.  I don't see any 'Summary' and I don't see any place to edit any settings.  Is it called something else, perhaps?

Comment: Ok, so it's not vSphere what are you using. Sorry! But I think VMware WS Player doesn't have a GUI option for that. So anyway you have to edit it's settings file manually.

Comment: I guess.  I did more research on this.  I can't find anything, at all, that works.  There are lots of recommendations, but I don't see anything, in my environment, that gives me any control for any of these settings.